# Bypass "mass assignement" laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I have hundreds of fields in my table and I don`t want to write all the field in the`$fillable`array. Is there any way to`bypass $fillable process` ?

```
class MyClass extends Eloquent {

protected $fillable = array('firstField', 'secondField',.......);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it the opposite way:

Specify the guarded attributes (all fields that should ***not*** be fillable).

```
protected $guarded = array('id', 'created_at', '...');
```

And remove the $fillable completely.